# Copy data between two strings excluding identifiers

Tags: perl

i want to read data between two strings and paste into new file....

```
open ($gen_xml,">test.xml") or die "can not open file $gen_xml : $!\n" ;

$i='start';
$j='end';
while($line = <$fh>){
    if ($line =~ /$i/../$j/) 
        { print $gen_xml $line; }
}
```

Comment: That's not very clear. Could you give an example.

Comment: An unrelated issue: You forgot to provide a pattern to `printf`. `printf $gen_xml $line;` should be `printf $gen_xml "%s", $line;` or `print $gen_xml $line;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following two lines in your code just above the print statement

```
$line=~s/$i//;
$line=~s/$j//;
```

Comment: thanks raju for replying......but its not working for example the text is...........' hi there START what are u doing END nothing much what about u END' ..... i need data between START and first END not the second.

Comment: I think u need to remove the anchors in the reg expression '^' and '$' see the edited one now.

Comment: i am trying to extract data from a file containing email. Now this mail has two attachments, when i extract between two strings `
my $i='PPAP.xls';

my $j='------_=_NextPart';` as there are two attachments the code copies till the next $j. Please help